# PHP divide by number but if not equal to number

Tags: php

I am trying to divide number to geners but if after that its less than 16 I want it to add the numbers from the less to 16 to the first gener in `foreach`.

```
        $geners = explode(",", $post['geners']); // $post['geners'] = 12,26,988
        $count = count($geners); // For example : 3
        $calc = (16 / $count); / 5.6666
        $total_each = number_format($calc, 0); // 5
        $total = ( $count * $total_each); // 15
    foreach ($geners as $key=>$gener){
        $gener_each = $total_each;
        if($total < 16){ // if 15 < 16
          $minus_16 = 16 - $total; // 15-16 = 1
          $gener_each[0]=$gener_each[0]+$minus_16; // First gener need to add $minus_16
        }
            echo $gener_each; // Need to be 6,5,5
        }
```

Comment: What is a "gener"?

Comment: You've (sort of) told us what you want to do, and you've shown us your code. In what way does it fail to do what you want?

Comment: @Chris All working but the last part of adding to the first gener.   $gener_each[0]=$gener_each[0]+$minus_16;

Comment: You still haven't told us what a "gener" is. As far as I know that's not an English word and your question doesn't make much sense without it. Though I doubt it makes much sense with it, either. Please read [ask].

Comment: $total_each is a formatted number, so a string. You assign that to $gener_each, and then you do math operations on $gener_each[0] ...?

Comment: What is  an example input for `$post['geners']`. Also, your loop is logically broken. It does the same thing three times

Comment: @Ice76 example : 26,988,55 - its category id.

Comment: `$gener_each` is a float.  But you're populating it with `$gener_each[0]` as if it's an array.  You're also not suing `$key`, `$gener`, or `$geners` within your loop.  I feel like there's a typo here, and that at least one of them should be.  These probably need to be corrected to make it clearer what you're trying to achieve.  As it stands right now, the content of `$post['geners']` is irrelevant beyond the number of commas it contains.

Comment: Is changing `if($total < 16){ // if 15 < ` to `if($gener < 16){ // if 15 < ` what you are after?

Comment: @Claymore This current foreach do 3 times, I want to change the value of the 1'st time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to divide 16 by an arbitrary number, create an array holding the same number of instances of that result as you have geners, round each instance of the divided result down to the nearest whole number, and then apply any remaining difference from a decimal result to the first in the set.

The following is untested, but have a look:

```
$geners = explode(',', $post['geners']);
$firstGener = current($geners);
$count = count($geners);
$calc = (16 / $count);
$floor = floor($calc);
$decimal = $calc - $floor;

$totals = [];
foreach ($geners as $gener) {
    $totals[$gener] = $floor;
    $totals[$firstGener] += $decimal;
}
//This is just in case a decimal result of an infinite number of digits, truncated by PHP itself, results in this value erroneously looking something like 5.9999999999999
$totals[$firstGener] = round($totals[$firstGener]);

//Since the value of $totals[$geners[0]] isn't done calculating until the completion of the above loop, presentation of each value needs to be handled in a separate one here:
foreach ($totals as $gener => $totals) {
    echo "$gener - $total<br>"; 
}
```

Comment: Its worked but I still need in the for the value of $gener .
foreach ($calcs as $key=>$total){
        echo "{$gener} - {$total} <br>";
       }

Comment: That actually explains a lot.  Please see the edit and let me know if this is what you're looking for.